# ASP.net simple rewrite rule

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, no-www

I'm trying to rewrite non www to www domains.

I've tried the rule:

```
<rewrite url="http://domain\.com(.+)" to="http://www.domain.com$1" />
```

But to no avail.  It just continues to allow access to htttp://domain.com

Comment: technically, htttp://domain.com is allowed (even without the typo), though, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are refering to [this one](http://urlrewriter.net/) ("Intelligencia URL Rewriter").

As described in their documentation, you have to [add the configuration section handler](http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/configuration) as well as other configuration settings to your `web.config` file before you can start adding rewrite/redirect rules.

**Update**

Just saw you modified your question, so probably you managed to find the configuration issue.

For your domain issue, I handled something similar in one of my projects like this:

```
<!-- Ensure that all are on the same top domain and sub domain. -->
<unless header="HTTP_HOST" match="www.zeta-producer.com">
    <redirect 
        url="^(.*)$" 
        to="http://www.zeta-producer.com$1" 
        processing="stop" />
</unless>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's all setup fine though as all my other rules (~100 of them) work perfectly.